# "Div" is not defined

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to learn som jQuery. I am having a issue where the error tells me that the "DIV" i am referring to is not defined...

I have defined my 4 DIVS, please help me with finding what I have done wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>jQuery Test 3</title>




</head>

<body>

<section id="buttons">
<label>Enter ID: </label>
<input id="idChooseTxt" type="text"><br>
<input id="fadeOutBtn" type="button" value="Fade Out">
<input id="fadeInBtn" type="button" value="Fade In">
<input id="slideUpBtn" type="button" value="Slide Up">
<input id="slideDownBtn" type="button" value="Slide Down">

</section>


<section id="mineDiver"></section>




<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){    


    var $idChooseTxt;
    var $fadeOutBtn, $fadeInBtn;
    var $slideUpBtn, $slideDownBtn;



    function setHTMLObjects(){

    $idChooseTxt = $("#idChooseTxt");
    $fadeOutBtn = $("#fadeOutBtn");
    $fadeInBtn = $("#fadeInBtn");
    $slideUpBtn = $("#slideUpBtn");
    $slideDownBtn = $("#slideDownBtn");


    };





    function setEvents(){

     $("#fadeOutBtn").click(fadingOut);
    $("#fadeInBtn").click(fadingIn);
        $("#slideUpBtn").click(slidingUp);
        $("#slideDownBtn").click(slidingDown);

    };

    function myDivs(){    
   var $Div1 = $("<div>")
    .css(
        {
            height: "200px",
            width: "200px",
            background: "black",
            marginTop: "10px",
            marginLeft: "10px",
            float: "left"
        })


            $("#mineDiver").append($Div1);



    var $Div2 = $("<div>")
    .css
    (
        {
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px",
            background: "red",
            marginTop: "10px",
            marginLeft: "10px",
            float: "left"
        })

    $("#mineDiver").append($Div2);



    var $Div3 = $("<div>")
              .css
              (
              {
              width: "200px",
              height: "200px",
              background: "yellow",
              marginTop: "10px",
              marginLeft: "10px",
              float: "left"
              })

    $("#mineDiver").append($Div3);





    var $Div4 = $("<div>")
    .css 
    (
        {
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px",
            background: "blue",
            marginTop: "10px",
            marginLeft: "10px",
            float: "left"

        })

    $("#mineDiver").append($Div4);



    }

    function fadingOut(){

    var divChosen = $idChooseTxt.val();

        if(divChosen === "div1"){
            $($Div1).fadeOut(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div2"){
            $($Div2).fadeOut(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div3"){
            $($Div3).fadeOut(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div4"){
            $($Div4).fadeOut(1000);

        }
    };
      function fadingIn(){

    var divChosen = $idChooseTxt.val();

        if(divChosen === "div1"){
            $($Div1).fadeIn(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div2"){
            $($Div2).fadeIn(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div3"){
            $($Div3).fadeIn(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div4"){
            $($Div4).fadeIn(1000);

        }
    };

      function slidingUp(){

    var divChosen = $idChooseTxt.val();

        if(divChosen === "div1"){
            $($Div1).slideUp(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div2"){
            $($Div2).slideUp(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div3"){
            $($Div3).slideUp(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div4"){
            $($Div4).slideUp(1000);

        }
    };


      function slidingDown(){

    var divChosen = $idChooseTxt.val();

        if(divChosen === "div1"){
            $($Div1).slideDown(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div2"){
            $($Div2).slideDown(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div3"){
            $($Div3).slideDown(1000);
        }else if(divChosen === "div4"){
            $($Div4).slideDown(1000);

        }
    };
    var init = function(){
        setHTMLObjects();
        setEvents();
        myDivs();
    }();
});







</script>









</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Nitpick. If @Div1 is a jQuery object, there is no reason to wrap it in a $() again.

Comment: you do not need `var $Div1` just use `var Div1`

Comment: I tried that now. Still not working...

Comment: @erkaner changing the naming convention is not going to solve anything.

Comment: @epascarello I know but I guess it is not a good practice to use `$` because it may create confusion and I do not want him to have this habit from the beginning.

Comment: @erkaner I am not sure what confusion it makes. Appending $ is a normal practice with variables that hold jQuery objects. I am not a fan, but it is common naming convention in the jQuery world.

Comment: @erkaner It doesn't cause confusion. putting a `$` in front of the variable  lets' the coder and anyone who contributes to the code know that it's a jquery selector.

Comment: I think I am wrong about then, thanks for correcting me. A question: are these Div1 variables different from each other `var Div1 = $("<div>")` and `var $Div1 = $("<div>")`

Comment: The only difference is there is a $ in the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Div#` are defined as local variables to the `myDivs` method. You can not access them outside. They are not global.

```
function myDivs(){    
   var $Div1 = $("<div>")  <-- var makes it local
}
```

---

Add the variables

```
var $idChooseTxt;
var $fadeOutBtn, $fadeInBtn;
var $slideUpBtn, $slideDownBtn;
var $Div1, $Div2, $Div3, $Div4;
```

and drop the var in the function myDivs

```
function myDivs(){    
   $Div1 = $("<div>")...
   $Div2 = $("<div>")...
   $Div3 = $("<div>")...
   $Div4 = $("<div>")...
}
```

Comment: how to make it accessible=

Comment: drop the var and make it global is one way.

Comment: It is working without adding the variables at the top...I must add them there aswell?

Comment: Keeps them from being global. It will work either way.